# Как добавить маску в инпут?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть свой компонент Input, менять который нежелательно. и мне нужно сделать маску. Но во всех плагинах предлагают уже маскированный свой инпут. 
Например, https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/react#readme

```
 <div>
    <MaskedInput mask={['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]} />
  </div>
```

Какие есть варианты в данном случае? Может быть сможете что-то посоветовать

Comment: так тебе нужно сделать маску или нельзя менять свой компонент?

Comment: Нужно сделать маску для инпута. Но компонент менять нельзя и ничего дополнительно прописывать тоже. Он импортируется. Свойства маски у него нет. Может быть как-то обертку сделать
как здесь
https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/master/react/src/reactTextMask.js

еще есть некий https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-mask-core

Comment: Может быть есть популярный плагин маски над инпутом, не затрагивая его